# What happens if a sorceress' dragon wings are damaged?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer

I have a 16th level sorceress who has just been taken hostage.  Her dragon wings have been cut and almost destroyed.

> At 14th level, you gain the ability to sprout a pair of dragon wings from your back, gaining a flying speed equal to your current speed. You can create these wings as a Bonus Action on Your Turn. They last until you dismiss them as a Bonus Action on Your Turn.

Does this paragraph from the Players Handbook mean that I am able to dismiss them and sprout a complete pair of wings?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yup.  You probably don't want to let your captors know that, though.  It will take a full round for her to recover the ability to fly: first, she loses the mutilated wings, and then she regrows new ones (both are bonus actions, so you can't do them in the same round, unless you have extra bonus actions).  Keep that in mind when picking the right gap in your captors' awareness and or readiness to exploit for your aerial escape.

Comment: There is no way to get "extra bonus actions". Regardless of the number of possible bonus actions granted by an number of sources, you can only ever take one.

Comment: @T.J.L. That's actually not true.  It's almost true, but a 17th level rogue gets a full extra turn the first round of each combat.  A 17th level rogue/14th level sorceress could drop the wings, take an action to escape her binds, use a free object interaction to swipe the unguarded MacGuffin from the captors, jump off a cliff, regrow the wings, and fly twice her movement with the Dash action towards victory, lighting off a "mission success" firework as her free object interaction, all before her captors were given a single turn and all within one round.